# sum amount by next years mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have problem with one query.

I have this Orders table:

```
workerID orderID Year orderCount
274      869     2008   14
274      758     2006    2
274      770     2006   13
274      853     2006   10
```

And I need to create table like this one:

```
workerID orderID Year orderCount sumByYears
274      2005     30 (orderCount for year 2005)
274      2006    880 (orderCount for year 2005+2006)
274      2007   1456 (orderCount for year 2005+2006+2007)
274      2008    729 (...)
```

Its easy for me to write this query:

```
SELECT workerID , Year , SUM(orderCount) 
FROM Orders
GROUP BY workerID , Year 
ORDER BY workerID , Year ;
```

But I do not know how to get the last column.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is commonly called a running total. In SQL Server 2012, you can use `SUM() OVER ()` to calculate it.

```
SELECT
  workerID,
  Year,
  orderCount = SUM(orderCount),
  sumByYears = SUM(SUM(orderCount)) OVER (PARTITION BY workerID ORDER BY Year) 
FROM Orders
GROUP BY workerID , Year 
ORDER BY workerID , Year ;
```

Read more about the OVER clause here:

- [OVER clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Comment: This is exactly what i need. Thank you all for your help. I love stackoverflow! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want a literal string This should do it:

```
SELECT workerID , Year , SUM(orderCount), '(orderCount for year' + Year + ')'
FROM Orders
GROUP BY workerID , Year 
ORDER BY workerID , Year ;
```

If what you're really after is the rolling sum of the order counts by year then I believe this should work:

```
   SELECT workerID 
    , Year 
    , SUM(orderCount)
    , (SELECT SUM(orderCount)
        FROM Orders As runningORders
        WHERE runningOrders.Year <= Orders.Year         
    ) As SumByYears
FROM Orders
GROUP BY workerID , Year 
ORDER BY workerID , Year ;
```

Here's a sample [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/337f4/3)

Comment: The second query is what I nead but I get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'." I am working now to correct this query

Comment: Oops, I think the WHERE should go before the Group By updating now.

Comment: Of course, I'm sorry I did not notice. But now I see this: "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Comment: Change the subselect to `, (SELECT SUM(orderCount)
        FROM Orders As runningORders
        WHERE runningOrders.Year <= Orders.Year         
    ) As SumByYears`  -- This will correct the "Only one expression..." error.

Comment: now I think that GROUP BY is wrong "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression." If I delete GROUP BY I get wrong sum because 30 + 880 = 910 (look up for example of table) and I got 72766 and this value repeats for all of 2007

Comment: Ok look at screen and you will see my result http://oi39.tinypic.com/34o34mh.jpg Sum in last column is wrong

Comment: It looks like this works fine for me. Here is an edited fiddle with your example numbers:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/250ba/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT workerID , Year , 
SUM(orderCount), '(orderCount for year' + Year + ')'
FROM Orders
GROUP BY workerID , Year 
ORDER BY workerID , Year ;
```